# Overriding function in module in Lua 5.1

Tags: lua

I'm writing a Lua program, in which there are lots of modules that is independent from each other. Every module keeps related source files in its folder. What I want is to override `require` function in each module so that when `require` called, file in module folder is loaded.

Assume that I have modules below and each of them has a file named `utils.lua`:

```
src
├── module1
│   ├── main.lua
│   └── utils.lua
├── module2
│   └── utils.lua
├── module3
│   └── utils.lua
└── utils.lua
```

and I'm writing `module1.main`. I want ability to write something like

```
require 'utils' -- load module1.utils actually.

-- Do something...
```

Any good idea?

Notes: I need `require` for I have some custom searchers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not writing ?

```
local utils = require "module1.utils"
```

if you don't choose to do so, the proper way to change the require behavior is to add your own function to [package.loaders](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.loaders).